# Use 'Average()' On EF CORE (C# .NET CORE)

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I use .NET CORE for a while now
and i noticed that some queries run really strange, so i did some profiling and i noticed that some queries and running in parts on the database, instead of getting it in 1 shot.
So i turned off the option 'QueryClientEvaluation' from EF core and i keep getting error

```
  The LINQ expression 'Average()' could not be translated and will be evaluated locally.
```

which is very strange because i used the `Average` function in EF6 till now with no issue, so why should it need to use QueryClientEvaluation??

here is a simple sample `_context.Reviews.Select(r => r.Rating).Average()`

Comment: Can you include the query you are trying to execute?

Comment: Please provide some code, we can check it better

Comment: added sample as requested

Comment: Are you getting same error? after update

Comment: yes getting same issue, in 1 case the application just hangs with no response

Comment: *which is very strange* Not at all. EF-core is a completely new product.

Comment: Yup i learned it the hard way 

Answer (score 4):

Which version are you using?

It was a bug [#7190](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFrameworkCore/issues/7190) that has been fixed at version [2.0.0-preview1](http://2.0.0-preview1). You can also have latest released version [2.0.0](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFrameworkCore/releases/tag/rel%2F2.0.0) .

Comment: i just spent an hour upgrading the application to find that same error is happening in 2.0, 

Comment: @CMS Additionally to upgrading, you need to promote the result type to nullable, e.g. `_context.Reviews.Select(r => (decimal?)r.Rating).Average() ?? 0` (replace `decimal` with `Rating` property type)

Comment: OK THANKS!!! got it to work, and YES the issue was that i needed (decimal?) AND for some reason i needed to remove the async is NOT it was just getting stuck